refer to a specific anchor as with reload website
is it possible that when the page is reloaded in the browser, an anchor/tag is addressed and automatically goes to this jumping point?
Best regards
I have found this function
window.location.reload();
but I am looking for something that recognizes the reload and executes a simple function

Does this answer your question? How do I redirect to another webpage?

window.location = '#anchor'; does the navigation that you want. For recognising a reload, have a look at the history api

Use a variable in sessionStorage to save the ID of the div you want to scroll to when the page is reloaded.


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let savePos = sessionStorage.getItem("position");
  if (position) {
    let target = document.getElementById(savePos);
    if (target) {
      target.scrollIntoView();
    }
    sessionStorage.removeItem("position"); // only use it once
  }
});

function savePosition(div) {
  sessionStorage.setItem(div.id);
}



